# Laravel rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

I have .htaccess

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^wniosek.html$ index.php/wniosek [L]
```

My routes.php looks like this:

```
Route::resource('/', 'HomeController@showIndex');
Route::resource('/wniosek', 'HomeController@showTest');
```

After I go to example.com/wniosek.html I get:

```
NotFoundHttpException;
```

Could anyone help me with that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to access this URL:

```
http:://youdomain.com/wniosek
```

Then your rule should include the whole url and send it to `/wniosek`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/wniosek.html$ /wniosek [L]
```